# Validating user's input while using a while loop

Tags: validation, loops, input, while-loop, csc

My issue is that I'm trying to validate my input by making sure that the while loop only takes a number more than 10.  If not, they have to try again.  But the issue I'm having is that the loop keeps repeating itself if I close the while loop.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
/**
* @(#)Hotel_Occupancy.java
*
* Hotel_Occupancy application
*
* @author 
* @version 1.00 2013/10/28
*/

public class Hotel_Occupancy {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Declare Variables
        int floors;
        int rooms;
        int roomsOccupied;
        int roomsVacant;
        int occupancyRate;

        //Create Scanner Object
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Ask user for # of floors 
        System.out.print("Enter floors? Input number more than 1. ");
            floors = keyboard.nextInt();

        while (floors < 1 && floors != 10 )
        {   
            System.out.println("ENTER VALID NUMBER.");
            System.out.println("Enter floors? Input number more than 1. ");
            System.;

            //Create loop with floor iteration
            for (rooms = 1; rooms <= floors; rooms++)
            {   
                System.out.println("How many rooms? ");
                rooms = keyboard.nextInt();
            }

            for (roomsOccupied = 1; roomsOccupied <= rooms; roomsOccupied++)
            {   
                System.out.println("How many rooms occupied? ");
                roomsOccupied = keyboard.nextInt();
                roomsVacant = rooms - roomsOccupied;
                System.out.println("Rooms Vacant" + roomsVacant);
            }

            //Calculate Occupancy Rate
            occupancyRate = roomsOccupied + rooms;
            System.out.println("Occupancy rate is " + occupancyRate);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`while(floor >=10){
// Do whatever you want
}`
Go through this basic [while loop tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html).